Equivalent Definition of a Smooth Map Between Manifolds
I am reading John Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds at the moment. In the text, two definitions of a smooth map $F:M\to N$, where $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, are given, and it is stated that they're equivalent.
The first definition is:

Let $M$, $N$ be smooth manifolds, and let $F:M\to N$ be any map. We say that $F$ is a smooth map if for every $p\in M$, there exist smooth charts $(U, \varphi)$ containing $p$ and $(V, \psi)$ containing $F(p)$ such that $F(U)\subseteq V$ and the composite map $\psi\circ F\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\varphi(U)$ to $\psi(V)$.

Okay, makes sense. We want to define smoothness in a way that's familiar to us, by using homeomorphisms to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that for any neighborhood of $p$, we look at it as an open subset $\varphi(U)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we get that $$\mathbb{R}^m\supseteq\varphi(U)\xrightarrow{\varphi^{-1}} U\xrightarrow{F} F(U)\xrightarrow{\psi}\psi(F(U))\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n.$$
Now, an important observation here is that $F(U)\subseteq V$. This makes sense, since $\psi$ is only defined on $V$. Next, Lee proposes an equivalent definition:

For every $p\in M$, there exist smooth charts $(U, \varphi)$ containing $p$ and $(V, \psi)$ containing $F(p)$ such that $U\cap F^{-1}(V)$ is open in $M$ and the composite map $\psi\circ F\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\varphi(U\cap F^{-1}(V))$ to $\psi(V)$.

I am having a hard time understanding this second definition, and moreso, why it's an equivalent one. If $F(U)\subseteq V$, isn't $U\cap F^{-1}(V)$ just $U$? Why add this extra stipulation? If $F(U)\not\subseteq V$, then how is $\psi:F(U)\to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined? Isn't $\psi$ only defined on $V$? If it's not, but instead is only defined on $F(U\cap F^{-1}(V))$, why are we allowed to "shrink" $U$ to $U\cap F^{-1}(V)$ and get an equivalent definition?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

First step. Change one $V$ to $W$.  And Lee never says that $\psi$ is defined on $F(U)$ in the second case, does he?

The second follows from the first as you have explained.
Now suppose that the second holds. Let $p \in M$ and $(U,\varphi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ be charts as in the second definition. Take the new chart $(U\cap F^{-1}(V), \varphi|_{U\cap F^{-1}(V)})=:(W,\phi)$. By assumption, $W$ is open and therefore $(W,\phi)$ is indeed a chart. Then $p \in W$ and $F(W)\subseteq V$ and $\psi\circ F \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(W) \to \psi(V)$ is smooth, since $\psi\circ F \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\varphi(U\cap F^{-1}(V)) = \phi(W)$ to $\psi(V)$.
You don't need $\psi$ to be defined on $F(U)$. Further, the openness condition for $U\cap F^{-1}(V)$ is automatically satisfied if $F$ is continuous.

Thank you for the time and effort you spent in writing this response. This makes sense, as we are just finding another chart $(W, \phi)$ which would give us the first definition.

Lee's first definition says that

For each $p \in M$ there exist charts $(U,\varphi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ around $p$ and $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subset V$ and
$$\mathbb{R}^m \supseteq \varphi(U) \xrightarrow{\varphi^{-1}} U \xrightarrow{F} V \xrightarrow{\psi}\psi(V) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \tag{1}$$
is smooth.

Note that $F(U) \subseteq V$ is equivalent to $U \subseteq F^{-1}(V)$.
Lee's second definition says that

For each $p \in M$ there exist charts $(U,\varphi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ around $p$ and $F(p)$ such that $U \cap F^{-1}(V)$ is open and
$$\mathbb{R}^m \supseteq \varphi(U \cap F^{-1}(V) ) \xrightarrow{\varphi^{-1}}  U \cap F^{-1}(V) \hookrightarrow F^{-1}(V) \xrightarrow{F} V \xrightarrow{\psi} \psi(V)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \tag{2}$$
is smooth.

Note that since $F(p) \in V$, the set $U \cap F^{-1}(V)$ is an open neighborhood of $p$.

Let $F$ be smooth in the sense of the first definition. Let $p \in M$. There exist charts $(U,\varphi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ around $p$ and $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subset V$ and
$$\mathbb{R}^m \supseteq \varphi(U) \xrightarrow{\varphi^{-1}} U \xrightarrow{F} V \xrightarrow{\psi}\psi(V) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $$
is smooth.
These charts satisfy all requirements of the second definition:
As you write, since $U \subseteq F^{-1}(U)$, we see that $U \cap F^{-1}(V) = U$. Thus $U \cap F^{-1}(V)$ is open and the map in $(1)$ agrees with the map in $(2)$ because $U \xrightarrow{F} V$ is nothing else than $U \hookrightarrow F^{-1}(V) \xrightarrow{F} V$.

Let $F$ be smooth in the sense of the second definition. Let $p \in M$. There exist charts $(U,\varphi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ around $p$ and $F(p)$ such that $U \cap F^{-1}(V)$ is open and
$$\mathbb{R}^m \supseteq \varphi(U \cap F^{-1}(V) ) \xrightarrow{\varphi^{-1}}  U \cap F^{-1}(V) \hookrightarrow F^{-1}(V) \xrightarrow{F} V \xrightarrow{\psi} \psi(V)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$$
is smooth.
Then $p \in U' = U \cap F^{-1}(V)$ so that the restriction $\varphi' = \varphi \mid_{U'}$ gives a nice chart $(U',\varphi')$ around $p$. The charts $(U',\varphi')$ and $(V,\psi)$ satisfy all requirements of the first definition:
We have $F(U') = F(U \cap F^{-1}(V)) \subset F(F^{-1}(V)) \subset V$ and the map in $(2)$ becomes
$$\mathbb{R}^m \supseteq \varphi'(U') \xrightarrow{(\varphi')^{-1}}  U' \hookrightarrow F^{-1}(V) \xrightarrow{F} V \xrightarrow{\psi} \psi(V)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n .$$
Of course $U' \hookrightarrow F^{-1}(V) \xrightarrow{F} V$ is nothing else than $U' \xrightarrow{F} V$.


